# How to fix "TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/login/django/forms/widgets/text.html" error in Django??'

Tags: python, django, django-admin

When I run

```
python manage.py runserver
```

it worked but when I want to login in "http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin" it doesn't work.

It gives me this message:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/login/django/forms/widgets/text.html
```

but I already created a superuser and I have django.contrib.admin installed in `setting.py`

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
         os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'venv/lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Why does this error occur? and how can I fix it?

Comment: In file `setting.py`, in `TEMPLATES` of your project, do you have `APP_DIRS: True` ?

Comment: can you edit your question to include your `settings.py` file's `TEMPLATES` code, as well as the path to your template in your project?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem so I've deleted the [FORM_RENDERER](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#form-renderer) in the settings.py and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
pip uninstall django
pip install django --no-cache-dir
```

I hope it works ^_^

Comment: it didn't work i don't know why plzzz help me solve it